# Sometimes App crashes because of IndexOutOfBounds Exception, sometimes it works

Tags: android, kotlin

I would like to code a Quizzapp in Android Studio using the programmming language kotlin. My app will show a football player with four answers (Names of other Football Players and the right one) that are displayed each on four buttons. What I want to achieve is that everytime the app gets openend, new questions would be displayed with also different answers that are false. Unfortunately, the app crashes due to a IndexOutOfBoundsExeption when clicking on one of the four buttons, but sometimes even when going from the MainActivity (I have got a starting screen that has a button) to the QuizActivity (Index: 6, Size:6). I hope this makes sense, heres the code of my QuizAcitivy.kt file:``

class QuizActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

```
lateinit var imageView : ImageView
lateinit var btnFirstAns : Button
lateinit var btnSecondAns : Button
lateinit var btnThirdAns : Button
lateinit var btnFourthAns : Button
lateinit var btnNext : Button
lateinit var btnCorrectAnswer : Button

lateinit var playerList: ArrayList<String>
lateinit var buttonList : ArrayList<Button>
lateinit var imageList : ArrayList<Int>
lateinit var correctAnswer: String

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz)

    initializeViewsAndLists()

    val question = generateQuestion()
    correctAnswer = question.first.first
    val correctImage = question.first.second
    val options = question.second

    btnFirstAns.text = options[0]
    btnSecondAns.text = options[1]
    btnThirdAns.text = options[2]
    btnFourthAns.text = options[3]

    imageView.setImageResource(correctImage)

    btnFirstAns.setOnClickListener { checkAnswer(btnFirstAns.text.toString(), correctAnswer) }
    btnSecondAns.setOnClickListener { checkAnswer(btnSecondAns.text.toString(), correctAnswer) }
    btnThirdAns.setOnClickListener { checkAnswer(btnThirdAns.text.toString(), correctAnswer) }
    btnFourthAns.setOnClickListener { checkAnswer(btnFourthAns.text.toString(), correctAnswer) }
}

fun generateQuestion(): Pair<Pair<String, Int>, List<String>> {
    val index = playerList.indices.random()
    val correctAnswer = playerList[index]
    val correctImage = imageList[index]
    val wrongAnswers = playerList.filter { it != correctAnswer }.shuffled().take(3)
    val options = (wrongAnswers + correctAnswer).shuffled()
    return Pair(correctAnswer to correctImage, options)
}

fun checkAnswer(userInput: String, correctAnswer: String) {

    if(userInput.equals(correctAnswer)){
        //Toast.makeText(this, "Richtig", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        btnWithCorrectAnswer()?.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00FF00"))
        //btnWithCorrectAnswer()?.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.correct_button)
        btnWithCorrectAnswer()?.isEnabled = false
    } else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "Falsch!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

    }
}
fun btnWithCorrectAnswer(): Button? {
    val correctButton : Button? = null
    //val correctAnswer = generateQuestion().first.first
    if (btnFirstAns.text == correctAnswer)
        return btnFirstAns
    else if (btnSecondAns.text == correctAnswer)
        return btnSecondAns
    else if (btnThirdAns.text == correctAnswer)
        return btnThirdAns
    else if (btnFourthAns.text == correctAnswer)
        return btnFourthAns
    return null
```

}

```
private fun initializeViewsAndLists() {
    imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView)
    btnFirstAns = findViewById(R.id.btn_firstAns)
    btnSecondAns = findViewById(R.id.btn_secondAns)
    btnThirdAns = findViewById(R.id.btn_thirdAns)
    btnFourthAns = findViewById(R.id.btn_fourthAns)
    btnNext = findViewById(R.id.button_next)

    playerList = ArrayList<String>()
    playerList.add("Neymar Junior")
    playerList.add("Cristiano Ronaldo")
    playerList.add("Lionel Messi")
    playerList.add("Thomas Müller")
    playerList.add("Killian Mbappe")
    playerList.add("Arian Robben")
    playerList.add("Josua Kimmich")
    playerList.add("David Alaba")

    imageList = ArrayList<Int>()
    imageList.add(R.drawable.neymar)
    imageList.add(R.drawable.ronaldo)
    imageList.add(R.drawable.messi)
    imageList.add(R.drawable.mueller)
    imageList.add(R.drawable.mbappe)
    imageList.add(R.drawable.robben)

    buttonList = ArrayList<Button>()
    buttonList.add(btnFirstAns)
    buttonList.add(btnSecondAns)
    buttonList.add(btnThirdAns)
    buttonList.add(btnFourthAns)
}
```

}`

I tried many things to solve the problem myself, for example instead of writing
`if (btnFirstAns.text == generateQuestion().first.first) return btnFirstAns`
I wrote
`if (btnFirstAns.text == correctAnswer) return btnFirstAns`
I did that because I encounterd IndexOutOfBoundsExeptions with the above code before, because everytime I checked which button has the correct answer, new Values were created leading to a IndexOutOfBoundsExeptions. When I changed that the app worked at first, but after trying again it crashed.
EDIT: This is the error message I got after clicking the button that starts Quizactivity:

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.footballquizapp, PID: 8219
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.footballquizapp/com.example.footballquizapp.QuizActivity}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 7, Size: 6
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3162)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3305)
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1993)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7266)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:975)
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 7, Size: 6
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
at com.example.footballquizapp.QuizActivity.generateQuestion(QuizActivity.kt:58)
at com.example.footballquizapp.QuizActivity.onCreate(QuizActivity.kt:37)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7353)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7344)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1275)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3142)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3305) 
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1993) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7266) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:975)

Comment: Can you supply the full error message?

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is in this method.

```
fun generateQuestion(): Pair<Pair<String, Int>, List<String>> {
    val index = playerList.indices.random()
    val correctAnswer = playerList[index]
    val correctImage = imageList[index]
    val wrongAnswers = playerList.filter { it != correctAnswer }.shuffled().take(3)
    val options = (wrongAnswers + correctAnswer).shuffled()
    return Pair(correctAnswer to correctImage, options)
}
```

Your player list has 7 items, but imageList has only 6. So when the randomizer gives you 7 index and you try to pick the image you give the IndexOutOfBound exception.

As solution, you must have lists with identical sizes or randomly fetch items with the correct index according to each list.